# Magento 2 CE - backend system.xml page tree

Tags: magento2.3, cms

Is there any way to add to a config variable Cms PageID order wise (like a drag and drop) in configuration?

I use a simple cms page retriever but there is no option to order page.

```
<source_model>Magento\Cms\Model\Config\Source\Page</source_model>
```

Thank you.

Comment: So as far as I understand you have multiselect in which you can select multiple cms pages and want to have an ability to sort them?

Comment: that's correct. @underser